# iOS - UISearchController - definesPresentationContext layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with the navigation bar `HIDDEN`, a couple of buttons up top, and `UITableView` with a `UISearchController` as a header.
Here is the issue: when I create the `UISearchController`, I also have this line:

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Now what happens is that when I search using the `UISearchController`, and click on one of the results in the `UITableView`, it opens my following `UIViewController` (which is exactly what it is supposed to do -- and the following `UIViewController` also has the navigation bar hidden) correctly but it displays a grayish navigation bar at the top of the `UIViewController`, even though I'm setting the navigation bar as hidden.

Now when I set:

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
```

The navigation bar does not appear in the following view but instead of that, the `UISearchController's SearchBar` appears in the following `UIViewController` at the same place as it was in the main view controller, even though it's obviously not supposed to be there anymore.

This is what it's supposed to look like (top of the UIViewController):
[image]

This is what happens when `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

[image]

And this is what happens when `self.definesPresentationContext = NO;

[image]

How can I get back to situation number one?
**UPDATE**
Here is a sample project that duplicates this issue:
http://www.filedropper.com/sampleprojectbugreport

Comment: I think this is an Apple Bug. I have reported it. They have asked me for a sample project which I have provided.

Comment: As you said:- "the following UIViewController also has the navigation bar hidden) correctly but it displays a grayish navigation bar at the top of the UIViewController, even though I'm setting the navigation bar as hidden"... what code you have written to hide the navigation and where you have placed that.i.e on which method.

Comment: Where you are defining   self.definesPresentationContext = YES? in the 2nd view controller? how you are presenting the 2nd view controller through segue or navigation or modally? need code for that too.

Comment: Can you try changing the height of navigation bar to 0 instead of hiding the navigation bar in both views?

Comment: I have tried setting the height to 0, it doesn't work. I have attached a sample project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like a bug in iOS. If you're not planning on showing the navigation bar at all, you could subclass `UINavigationController` and override the `-setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method and hard-code the `hidden` value:

```
-(void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

I've tested this workaround and it prevents the navigation bar from showing.

See updated sample project: http://appsandwich.com/stackoverflow/navcontrollersubclass.zip

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but how do I subclass the UINavigationController? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: In Xcode, File -> New -> File... Under iOS Source, select Cocoa Touch Class. Then type UINavigationController in the subclass box.

Comment: I'll update the sample project and attach to my answer.

Comment: So I did File -> New -> File, under I subclassed UINavigationController and added the code (-(void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}) to it. But do I have to reference this VCNavigationController somewhere? It doesn't work yet

Comment: Yes, you need to init it in your AppDelegate.m, instead of the following line: UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:initialViewController];

Comment: Just #import your subclass and then replace UINavigationController with your new class name.

Comment: Yeah I managed to do it! It works...but the issue is that on some view I DO use the Navigation Bar...how can I use both cases?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do it. One would be to add a public method to your subclass that you can call to show the nav bar from other view controllers. That method would call [super setNavigationBarHidden:...animated:...]; I'll leave that one up to you :)

Comment: So wait, I made a method that called exactly that function, and I called it like this in my other ViewController where I wanted the bar to appear:
    VCViewController *viewControl = [[VCViewController alloc] init];
    [viewControl setNavigationBarShown];
Why isn't it working? Sorry I'm not very familiar with subclassing..

Comment: You need to add the method to your UINavigationController subclass. Then in your view controllers call [self.navigationController setNavigationBarShown];

Comment: I have added the method to my subclass but when I do [self.navigationController this method doesn't show up, I only get the native methods. How can I override this? I did everything in the app delegate and it works like you said it would, this is the only thing.

Comment: You need to cast it to your subclass: [(MySubclass *)self.navigationController setNavigationBarShown];

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved it using KVO.
I figure out in viewWillAppear(_:), navigationBar's `isHidden` is true. But in viewDidAppear(_:), navigationBar's `isHidden` changed to false. I don't know what happened. But I think I can capture and change it with KVO.

first, add observer in viewWillAppear(_:)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden", options: [.new], context: nil)
}
```

then, change navigationBar's `isHidden` in observerValue()

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }    
    if keyPath == "hidden" {
        // you should remove the KVO before set
        navigationController?.navigationBar.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "hidden")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    } else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

now the navigationBar is hidden as expected.
hope it helps.